# Change in function value

Tags: calculus

Let's suppose that $y=x^2$, $dy=2xdx$.

$\Delta y$ becomes equal to the sum of all $dy$ for all infinitesimal $dx$.

Let's suppose that $\Delta y = dy$ for infinitesimal $dx$: $(x+dx)^2 - x^2 = dy$

$x^2 + 2xdx + dx^2 - x^2 = 2xdx$

$2xdx + dx^2 = 2xdx$

But tangent line touches a curve $y=x^2$ at one point. How is it possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain more on how you went from that equation to the intersection of tangent line? It is not very clear, at least to me.

Comment: @ultralegend5385 Coefficient of tangent line at some point $x_0$: $dy/dx=2x_0$. We know that $\Delta y = dy$. If $2x_0dx+dx^2 = 2x_0dx$ then $dx^2=0$ and tangent line must touches the curve $y=x^2$ at 2 points: $(x_0;y_0)$ and $(x_0+dx;y_0+dy)$. But it's impossible.

Comment: Why is it impossible? A tangent line in naïve terms is just a secant through $(x_0;y_0)$ and $(x_0+\textrm dx;y_0+\textrm dy)$. Also tangent lines can touch a curve on any number of points in general, for example $y=1$ and $y=\sin(x)$. So it isn't an issue.